# Pass CVC to stripe.createPaymentMethod JS?

Tags: stripe-payments

I need a separate input for CVC and Expiry, so I have created 3 Stripe Elements:

```
let elements = stripe.elements();
let cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber');
cardNumber.mount('#card-number');

let cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry');
cardExpiry.mount('#card-expiry');

let cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc');
cardCvc.mount('#card-cvc');

...
```

[Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-payment-method) only mention about how to pass `card` or `cardNumber` Element to PaymentMethod, but how do I pass `cardExpiry` and `cardCvc`?

```
function paymentMethod() {
    return stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardNumber,
                billing_details: {
                    name: userName,
                    email: userEmail,
                },
    }).then(function(result) {
        // code
    });
 }
```

Stripe Docs only mention that

Comment: Stripe.js methods automatically use all the different elements on your page under the hood, so you don't need to pass CVC and Expiry elements manually, `createPaymentMethod` will do that automatically under the hood for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe.js methods automatically use all the different elements on your page under the hood, so you don't need to pass CVC and Expiry elements manually, createPaymentMethod will do that automatically under the hood for you.