# Passing CVC and Post Code Checks to createPaymentMethod stripe.js

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783206/pass-cvc-to-stripe-createpaymentmethod-js/58846109#58846109) and answer suggests that it is possible for stripe to verify CVC and post code (if these are being collected as seperate elements), but i cannot get it to work.

I am currently passing data as below. Im collecting the other details in a seperate form.

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod({
type: 'card',
card: cardNumber,
billing_details: {
    name: this.form.first_name + ' ' + this.form.last_name,
    address: {
    city: this.form.city,
    country: this.form.country,
    line1: this.form.address1,
    line2: this.form.address2,
    postal_code: this.form.zip,
    state: this.form.county
    },
    email:  this.form.email,
},
})
```

I am getting a valid paymentMethod response (so it is working),  but the checks (see below) are all coming back as null

```
checks:
address_line1_check: null
address_postal_code_check: null
cvc_check: null
```

Ive called the CVC and Expiry elements cardExpiry and cardCvc (trying to follow the convention given in the stripe docs where they use cardNumber), but i cannot see any details of how to pass these fields to allow the check.

Following the docs i have the following divs (example for CVC).  This is rendering and if i get errors then a message is being returned.

```
<div id="card-cvc" class="MyCardCvc">
    <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
</div>
```

The previously given answer suggests Stripe.js should do this under the hood, but i'm wondering if it needs a certain naming convention in order to pick up the fields automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case any else stumbles across this......

It would appear (after talking to stripe on irc) that these 'checks' are not performed during the initial submission of card details. Stripe does perform some sense checks on the card number and expiry date, but the below are validated only at the point of trying to complete the payment

```
checks:
address_line1_check: null
address_postal_code_check: null
cvc_check: null
```